# [__NSArrayI replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutablearray

I have a NSMutableArray, which I need to chance its values, but I have this error: 
**[__NSArrayI replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5291db0** 
This is the declaration of my NSMutableArray:

```
NSMutableArray *selectedOptions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:0], nil];
```

Then, I'm using replaceObjectAtIndex method, of this way:

```
[self.selectedOptions replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:1]];
```

But I get, that error, and I'm using NSMutableArray.
Thanks

Comment: You are creating an `NSArray` and storing it in an `NSMutableArray` variable.  This does not make it a mutable array.

Comment: Don't ignore compiler warnings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to initialize your `NSMutableArray` by doing

```
NSMutableArray *selectedOptions = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

By initializing it with `NSArray`, you can no longer use the `repalceObjectAtIndex:withObject:` method and that's the cause of your problem.

After initializing your `NSMutableArray` with the line above, simply add objects to it with the `addObject` method.

Answer (score 9):

You are creating a regular non-mutable `NSArray`. Your code should be

```
NSMutableArray *selectedOptions = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:0], nil];
```

Objective C is very dynamic, so it does not catch this mistake at compile time.

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought that pass a NSArray to NSMutableArray automatically changed its content to NSMutableArray